# Quadratic residue concept over Elliptic Curves

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ be an odd prime number and let me call $G = \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ the multiplicative group of the field $\mathbb{F}_p$, i.e. $G =  \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ if you prefer this notation. Here we can define the concept of *quadratic residue*,

> Let $a \in G$, then $a$ is a *quadratic residue* modulo $p$ if there exists $x \in G$ such that
> $$x^2 \equiv a \bmod p$$

Since $p$ is prime we now that there are $(p-1) / 2$ quadratic residues in $G$. This means that $$|G / G^2| = 2$$

Moreover, we know how to detect the class of $a$  in $G/G^2$  using the Legendre symbol and the Reciprocity Law. Furthermore, we know algorithms that allow us to compute the Legendre symbol very quickly.

Now, let me move into the field of Elliptic Curves and let me call $H = E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ the additive abelian group of the elliptic curve $E$ defined over the finite filed $\mathbb{F}_p$. From a well-know theorem we know that:

> $$ H \cong \mathbb{Z}_n \quad \text { or } \quad H \cong \mathbb{Z}_{n_1} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{n_2} $$
> for some integer $n \geq 1$ or integers $n_1,n_2 > 1$ such that $n_1 \, | \, n_2$.

Since we are working with additive groups the concept of quadratic residue fails. nevertheless, we can look for a *"double" residue* which means:

> Given a point $P \in H$, then there exists $Q \in H$ such that $$P = 2Q$$

However, here we have a lot of possibilities compared with those ones of multiplicative groups. Indeed, knowing the parity of $n$ or $n_1, n_2$ we discover that: $$ | H  / 2H | \in \{1,2,4 \} $$

Knowing this fact I ask myself (and you of course): is there an analogous of Reciprocity Law that allows us to detect in which class of $H/2H$ the point $P$ lies? If so, are there polynomial algorithms that allow us to make this computation?

Comment: It sounds like you are striving to describe "$2$-descent" on elliptic curves.

Comment: I don't know this construction. Can you link some information about it?

Comment: @AnginaSeng 2-descent normally refers to computing the rank of an elliptic curve over a number (global) field via the Selmer Group? At least to me this question is asking if a point is $2$-divisible in $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ which should be much easier?

Comment: @AnginaSeng can you give some references, please? Because Google only says about divisible polynomials, torsion points and stuff like that. I have not been able to find this argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the same concept for any finite abelian group $G$ and any positive integer $n$.

Let $e$ be the exponent of $G$. For any $n \in \mathbf{N}$, let $n' = \mathrm{gcd}(n, e)$. Then $G/nG \cong G[n']$, where the latter is the $n'$ torsion of $G$, induced by the map
$$G \to G[n']\\
g \mapsto (e/n')*g$$

In the case $G = \mathbf{F}_p^\times$ and $n = 2$, we have $e = p-1$ and recover the Legendre symbol
$$x \mapsto \left ( \frac{x}{p} \right ) = x^{e/2} \in \{\pm 1\} = (\mathbf{F}_p^\times)[2].$$

Let $E/\mathbf{F}_p$ be an elliptic curve. Let $H = E(\mathbf{F}_p) \cong \mathbf{Z}_{n_1} \oplus \mathbf{Z}_{n_2}$ with $n_1 \mid n_2$ (if $H$ is cyclic, just take $n_1 = 1$) and $P \in H$. We assume $2 \mid n_2$, otherwise $H/2H$ is trivial.

Then the class of $P$ in $H/2H$ is determined entirely by
$$(n_2/2) * P \in H[2] = E(\mathbf{F}_p)[2].$$
This, of course, can be computed in polynomial time.

Comment: The argument and the answer seem to be completely wrong.  The isomorphism works only for powers of cyclic groups (so already n₁=2, n₂=4 would give a counter-example).